# Одновременное изменение разных переменных одним методом путём асинхронности

Tags: c#, асинхронность

```cs
class Program
    {
        static int x, y, z;

        static int Factorial(int num)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start of method");
            int result = 1;

            for(int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
            {
                result *= i;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(4000);
            Console.WriteLine("End of method");
            num = result;
            return result;
        }

        static async void FactorialAsync(int num_1, int num_2, int num_3)
        {
            Task _x = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_1));
            Task _y = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_2));
            Task _z = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_3));

            Task[] tasks = new Task[3] { _x, _y, _z };
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Main");

            x = 4; y = 2; z = 3;

            FactorialAsync(x, y, z);

            Console.WriteLine($"x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}");
            Console.WriteLine("End Main");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine($"x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}");
        }
    }
```

Ф-ция `Factorial(int)` имитирует сложную задачу, которая занимает некоторое время и в итоге она изменяет входящий параметр на результат и возвращает сам же результат.

В методе `FactorialAsync(int, int, int)` реализуется включение нескольких потоков одновременно, которые выполняют метод  `Factorial(int)`.

Цель программы вообще - изменить 3 переменных одновременно одним и тем же методом путём асинхронизации. Но в итоге этого не происходит. В методе `Factorial(int)` изменял модификации параметров кл.словом `ref`, но результатов не дало.

P.S. Вот только начал знакомиться с асинхронизацией, суть вроде как понял. Просто вот пришла такая идея для практики, но всё как всегда идёт не по плану). И вообще возможно ли такая реализация или вообще бред?)

ЗЫ ах да, вывод проги такой, если что:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) познайте разницу между значимыми и ссылочными типами

Comment: 2) почитайте разницу между параллельностью и асинхронностью

Comment: 3) вот это `Task.Run` не всегда означает создание нового потока. Если вам обязательно надо создать поток, есть класс Thread для этого

Comment: `в итоге она изменяет входящий параметр на результат и возвращает сам же результат` она не меняет входящий параметр. Она меняет просто переменную, где раньше было значение входящего параметра. Если я вам вышлю письмо на емейл, а вы его сохраните в файлик, а потом файлик поменяете, это не значит, что письмо, что я вам выслал, тоже поменяется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось решить таким способом:

```cs
 class Program
    {
        static int _x, _y, _z;

        static int Foo(int x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Start Foo");
            int result = 1;
            for(int i = 1; i <= x; ++i)
            {
                result *= i;
            }

            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            Console.WriteLine("End Foo");
            return result;
        }

        static async Task<int> FooAsyncHandle(int x)
        {
            return await Task<int>.Run(() => Foo(x));
        }

        static async void SmthAsync(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            Task<int> task_1 = FooAsyncHandle(x);
            Task<int> task_2 = FooAsyncHandle(y);
            Task<int> task_3 = FooAsyncHandle(z);

            await Task.WhenAll(task_1, task_2, task_3);

            _x = task_1.Result;
            _y = task_2.Result;
            _z = task_3.Result;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            _x = 0; _y = 0; _z = 0; 
            Console.WriteLine("Start Main");
            Console.WriteLine($"x: {_x}, y: {_y}, z: {_z}");

            SmthAsync(5, 2, 3);

            Console.WriteLine("EndMain");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine($"x: {_x}, y: {_y}, z: {  _z}");
        }
    }
```

В методе `Main()` запускается асинхронный поток `SmthAsync(int, int, int)`, который в свою очередь инициализирует 3 разные задачи, которые выполняют один и тот же асинхронный метод, который запускает `Foo`.

```cs
        static async void SmthAsync(int x, int y, int z)
        {
            Task<int> task_1 = FooAsyncHandle(x);
            Task<int> task_2 = FooAsyncHandle(y);
            Task<int> task_3 = FooAsyncHandle(z);

            await Task.WhenAll(task_1, task_2, task_3);

            _x = task_1.Result;
            _y = task_2.Result;
            _z = task_3.Result;
        }
```

После выполнения этих "сложных" задач в асинхронном режиме (`await Task.WhenAll(task_1, task_2, task_3)`), объекты `task_1`, `task_2`, `task_3` просто возвращают значения для моих переменных `_x`,`_y`,`_z`. Таким образом, не нужно указывать ф-цию `Main` как асинхронную, следовательно, основной поток не останавливается, а изменение 3ех переменных происходит как бы в "фоновом" режиме, как я и задумал)

Comment: Так ведь это то же самое, только создание задач вынесено в отдельный метод (из-за этого, кстати, появляется лишнее ожидание await, что неэффективно). Ваш код ждёт завершения задач в `Console.ReadKey()`. Уберите из моего кода await и поставьте ReadKey - будет то же самое поведение.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш метод `Factorial` возвращает результат. Этот результат нужно использовать.

Изменим метод `FactorialAsync` следующим образом:

```
static async Task<int[]> FactorialAsync(int num_1, int num_2, int num_3)
{
    Task<int> _x = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_1));
    Task<int> _y = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_2));
    Task<int> _z = Task.Run(() => Factorial(num_3));

    Task[] tasks = new Task[3] { _x, _y, _z };
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return new int[] { _x.Result, _y.Result, _z.Result };
}
```

Задачи теперь имеют тип `Task<int>`, то есть у них есть результат. Возвращаем их результаты в виде массива. Можно создать отдельную структуру или использовать кортеж (tuple).

И, соответственно, используем значения, возвращаемые методом `FactorialAsync`:

```
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    x = 4; y = 2; z = 3;
    Console.WriteLine($"x: {x}, y: {y}, z: {z}");

    var result = await FactorialAsync(x, y, z);

    Console.WriteLine($"x: {result[0]}, y: {result[1]}, z: {result[2]}");
}
```

Метод `Factorial` оставлен без изменений.

---

Использовать `ref/out` при работе с асинхронными методами *невозможно*.

---

Я бы переписал метод так:

```
static async Task<int[]> FactorialAsync(params int[] input)
{
    var tasks = input
        .Select(n => Task.Run(() => Factorial(n)))
        .ToArray();

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return tasks
        .Select(t => t.Result)
        .ToArray();
}
```

---

Чтобы убедиться в одновременности выполнения нескольких задач, можно добавить вывод текущего Id таски.

```
static int Factorial(int num)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Start of method");
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= num; ++i)
    {
        result *= i;
        Console.WriteLine("Task Id: " + Task.CurrentId);
        Thread.Sleep(400);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("End of method");
    return result;
}
```

Вообще, запуск и выполнение задач/потоков зависит от множества факторов: наличие свободный потоков в пуле, количество ядер в процессоре, Debug/Release и многое другое. Если идентификаторы задач будут выводиться не вразнобой, как должно быть, то можно попробовать увеличить значения факториалов, скажем, на порядок.

Comment: Если мы метод `Main` указываем асинхронным и используем слово `await`, то программа в моменте `var result = await FactorialAsync(x, y, z);` не остановится ли программа? Для меня важно, чтобы эти три переменные изменились как бы в "фоновом" режиме, чтобы эти методы `Factorial()` выполнились асинхронно

Comment: @zZEN - дополнил ответ.

Comment: @zZEN - нет, остановится лишь _текущий_ поток, в котром выполняется метод Main. Вероятно, вам нужна событийная модель (event based). Но в рамках консольного приложения это имеет мало смысла.